# Setup Exchange 2007 ActiveSync web application on a separate server

Tags: iis-7, exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, activesync

I have Exchange 2007 installed on SBS 2008. I also run a web server on the network. I only have one static IP and all traffic trough port 443 is routed to the webserver.

I would like to publish the ActiveSync application externally. If i temporarily route 443 traffic to the SBS then it is published (along with owa and everything else which i don't want).

Is there a way to host the ActiveSync application on the web server (Server 2008 with IIS7) or to get it to route traffic meant for the ActiveSync application?

I have tried creating a site on the webserver which uses the ActiveSync folder on the SBS but that does not seem to work.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into running the Client Access role on the web server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996031(EXCHG.65).aspx

http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Introduction-Exchange-2007-Server-Roles.html

http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/09/12/428880.aspx